# i want to use sipp tool with asterisk server (need to integrate)

Tags: xml, csv, asterisk

i m implementing failover for asterisk server , so i have two server (active and passive)
initially asterisk service is running on active but if active fails the passive server should start the service .This is working perfectly as i have checked using x-lite softphone. but as i want to generate bulk calls i m using sipp tool , but it generates calls directly tht means if my asterisk server is off thn aslo it generates and tht too with any extensions , so i want to integrate sipp with asterisk server i.e sipp should generate calls if only asterisk server is ruuning. Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

You have check by external script if asterisk running and change ip in sipp.
Other option is create ip failover configuration(so one ip will move from one to other asterisk server).

See http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+High+Availability+Solutions

Comment: i have already made a failover script and its working. My question is i want to integrate sipp with asterisk server tht is sipp should generate calls only if astersik server is on

Comment: you can't integrate sipp in asterisk. you can generate calls via manager interface inside asterisk or can create script which will check if asterisk on and stop/start sipp.

Comment: without script is it possible to generate sip call through sipp which will go through asterisk server and thn to the sip client (soft phone)